# Run custom script as root user after completion of www-data user script

Tags: bash, cron, root, www-data

I have the following script to update the price, stocks and thereafter refresh the cache.
File: `/var/scripts/update-web.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date)"
echo "\n"
echo ======================= Updating Prices ======================="
source /var/scripts/update-prices.sh

echo "$(date)"
echo "\n"
echo ======================= Updating Stocks ======================="
source /var/scripts/update-stocks.sh

echo "$(date)"
echo "\n"
echo "======================= Refreshing cache ======================="
# @todo - This script should be run as root user after updating prices & stocks
source /var/scripts/clear-cache.sh

echo "$(date)"
echo "\n"
echo "[COMPLETED]"
```

This script is run as `www-data` user from `crontab`

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

with the following crontab entry:

```
1 0 * * * /var/scripts/update-web.sh > /tmp/update-web.txt
```

My main problem here is to run the `/var/scripts/clear-cache.sh` script as root user (immediately after updating prices & stocks).
Let me know if there's a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead run the www script from a root script

```
#!/bin/sh
su www-data -c /var/scripts/update-web.sh
/var/scripts/clear-cache.sh
```

Make a script like that and run it from root's crontab,
and remove the entry from www-data's crontab.